# How to validate an array in Laravel and return it's filtered values?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

So Laravel does not remove nested elements in an Array Validation. This is a problem for me because I'm trying to dynamically update relationships. If a user spoofs another Element, Laravel blows up and gives me the error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: country
```

I checked out where the problem is and it happens to be:

```
$request->validated()
```

If you like to test it out here is my test method:

```
/** @test */
public function test() {
    $result = $this->json('GET', route('test'), [
       'test' => ['a' => 'test a', 'b' => 'I should not be here'], 
       'isIgnored' => 'no one is seeing that']
    )->json());
}
```

In a controller you validate:

```
public function update()
{
   $validatedData = request()->validate([
       'test.a' => 'required'
     ]);
}
```

The result of $validatedData is

```
array:1 [
  "test" => array:2 [
       "a" => "test a"
       "b" => "I should not be here"
  ]
]
```

Perhaps you see that "isIgnored" was ignored, but test.b not. After that my controller is trying to update the model with

```
$user->$relation()->update($values);
```

and blows up. And I thought about using protected $fillable but still no success. It just doesn't ignore it.

I'm using sqlite for testing on Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Laravel source of `ValidatesRequests`, you'll see the following code:

```
/**
 * Validate the given request with the given rules.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  array  $rules
 * @param  array  $messages
 * @param  array  $customAttributes
 * @return array
 */
public function validate(Request $request, array $rules,
                         array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])
{
    $this->getValidationFactory()
         ->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes)
         ->validate();

    return $this->extractInputFromRules($request, $rules);
}

/**
 * Get the request input based on the given validation rules.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  array  $rules
 * @return array
 */
protected function extractInputFromRules(Request $request, array $rules)
{
    return $request->only(collect($rules)->keys()->map(function ($rule) {
        return Str::contains($rule, '.') ? explode('.', $rule)[0] : $rule;
    })->unique()->toArray());
}
```

What you see is caused by this line in the `map()` method:

```
return Str::contains($rule, '.') ? explode('.', $rule)[0] : $rule;
```

When a key contains a `.`, only the first element of that exploded string will be used. So in your case it will return all the data under the `test` key.

This method does not allow you to filter out specific array elements, you'll have to do this yourself. You already know what you want to validate, in your case `a`, so it wouldn't be difficult to strip out unwanted data.

Comment: I feared for that answer... because in my case I have about 10 nested elements and about 6 arrays... (about 40 elements that I need to check).

Comment: What's the contents of `$values` in your example?